# SUMPRODUCT bug on new table line

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where I put daily operations/data and another sheet where I *sum up* the daily results in just one line (total daily operations, profit, taxes, etc.).

I can do it just fine with SUMPRODUCT (since it needs to match more than two criteria: day, kind of operation (`DOLAR` or `INDICE`) and the actual content I want to sum), but when I hit TAB for a new line on this table (so I can make a line for each day), automatically it bugs! (`#N/A` for all cells).

[The file to download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lkiyij31z6fzn1/example.xlsx?dl=0) and example of formula that I am using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Mini_Table[Data]=[Data]);--(Mini_Table[Tipo]=D);--(Mini_Table[Contratos]))
```

Working fine:
[image]

Hit TAB to a new line:
[image]

The sheet of contents is this:
[image]

I tried with INDEX + MATCH, but I don't know how to SUM the results in this case.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `SUMIFS()`, it seems more suitable for what you want, and you don't need to juggle with these double minuses then. Also runs faster than `SUMPRODUCT()`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `=[Data]` with `=[@[Data]]`?

Comment: Replaced  `=[Data]` with `=[@Data]` and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Ps: _Data_  is "date" in Portuguese.